# How to insert a CSS tranform rotate animation in JS fadein and fadeout slideshow?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slideshow

I'm having an idea but I cannot apply it because I am not very familiar with Javascript. My problem is I have a JS script for fadein and fadeout slideshow, however, it seems to be nice to have a page rotation during transition. I have a CSS hover style to do this [.card:hover .card__side--front {transform: rotateY(-180deg); }] but I don't know how to integrate it in the JS script. Here is the JS script of the slideshow:

```
<script>
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(3000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(3000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow')
;
    ;
},  30000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
var imgDuration = 3000;

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);
    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

```css
#slider {
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 1s; 
}

#slider.fadeOut {
    opacity:0;
    transform: rotate(1800deg);
}
```

```html
<img id="slider" src="http://pngriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Download-Batman-Fidget-Spinner-PNG-Transparent-058.png">
```

I have changed the code from the following reference,

**REFERENCE:** http://jsfiddle.net/pdb4kb1a/2/

Comment: Hi Manish Khedekar, I tried your suggestion but i got only one transition because i removed the arrayed images. My pages are loaded from the database so how can I do it without the array?

Comment: @implanning I have changed the above code, please find the spinning bat and you can make it spin slowly by decreasing the angle of rotation nearer to 0deg.